# Decrypt ( with PHP ) a Java encryption ( PBEWithMD5AndDES )

Tags: java, php, encryption

I need your help. I was asked to decrypt strings via PHP, starting by this java class:

```
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;

import com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream;

public class Decryptor {

    private Cipher dcipher;

    private static final int iterationCount = 10;

    private static byte[] salt = {
        (byte) 0xB2, (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0xD5, (byte) 0xB2,
        (byte) 0x44, (byte) 0x21, (byte) 0xC3, (byte) 0xC3 };

    Decryptor(String passPhrase) {
        try {
            KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
            SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);
            AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);
            dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
            dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String decrypt(String str) {
        try {
            byte[] dec = BASE64DecoderStream.decode(str.getBytes());
            byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);
            return new String(utf8, "UTF8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

I don't know the Java language so I need some help to understand this encryption.

I tried to use this code:
https://github.com/KevinBusse/PBEWithMD5AndDES

But I can't "translate" the salt to PHP string and it doesn't seem to work.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried the salt `B212D5B24421C3C3`?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work, the function PbeWithMd5AndDes::decrypt returns bool(false). 

If I put $iterationsMd5 = 1 (in the Java class it's 10 I think) it returns some "strange" characters, something like "ƒ¿¤ûX·".

Comment: So why are you trying it with 1 if it should be 10?

Comment: Nothing more then curiosity, trying to understand. I thought it could be useful to say. As I said, if I put 10 the function returns false. The function also ask for another parameter, segments, but I don't find any reference in the java class. :(

Comment: I have to say that I encrypted some text using the PHP library, then decrypted it with the Java class (substituting the non-standard `BASE64DecoderStream` with Java 8 `Base64.Decoder`), and it worked perfectly. So either you have bad encrypted data or a bad passphrase, or you are not using the PHP call correctly. You should show your PHP usage code, and if you have encrypted data and passphrase that you can share, please add them as well.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, thank you. It seems they gave me the wrong data and salt. Now everything seem to work, I'm waiting for new data to try again and confirm that. Meanwhile, thank you for your help.

Comment: Repository moved to https://github.com/kevinsandow/PBEWithMD5AndDES

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, It worked for me.

Take your salt:

```
$bytes = array ( 0xB9,  0x2B, 0xC8,  0x32, 0x56,  0x35 ,  0xE3, 0x03 );
```

Convert it to String in php :

```
$salt = call_user_func_array(
    'sprintf',
    array_merge((array) str_repeat('%c', count($bytes)), $bytes)
);
```

Goto this repo: 
https://github.com/KevinBusse/PBEWithMD5AndDES

Goto class **PkcsKeyGenerator** and comment this code   **$salt = pack('H*', $salt);** like this.

```
function __construct($keystring, $salt, $iterationsMd5, $segments)
    {
       // $salt = pack('H*', $salt);
        $keyMaterial = '';
        $data = $keystring . $salt;
        $result = '';
        for ($j = 0; $j < $segments; $j++)
        {
            if ($j == 0)
            {
                $result = $data;
            }
            else
            {
                $result .= $data;
            }
            for ($i = 0; $i < $iterationsMd5; $i++)
            {
                $result = md5($result, true);
            }
            $keyMaterial .= $result;
        }
        $this->_key = substr($keyMaterial, 0, 8);
        $this->_iv = substr($keyMaterial, 8, 8);
    }
```

Now try.

Comment: Take a look at the last comment to the question.

Comment: Repository moved to https://github.com/kevinsandow/PBEWithMD5AndDES